# Creating module / package based project?

Tags: java, architecture

I'd like to create a project in Java that as a shell or box or controller for other parts of itself (there might be an adequate naming for it). I want it to be possible to load additional program parts after the installation of the program, like plugins or addons or how you might call them.

As an example one could think of a program called Calculator having a MenuBar on top giving the possibility to load several JFrames (or JInternalFrame) that provide different calculation ways, for instance ListSums, InvoiceSums, BreakEvenCalculator, ... (and so on).

Now what I want to create is a kind of mask giving me the possibility to import for instance a new JInternalFrame with weather calculations. Literally adding a couple of menu entries and a set of new masks. Well, and this kind of plugin or addon shall be downloaded from a link I provide.

I already tried myself in googling for some ways how to do that, but I'm not quite sure what to search for.

Is there any site providing information about how to create plugins or addons like this?

Cheers in advance for every helpful soul!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is not very specific I am not sure if I understood correctly but I will try to answer anyways.

I am guessing, that you want to load java code dynamically at runtime (without restart / recompile of your program).

So there are some different approaches to achieve that:

**1. Own "Framework"**

You create a generic GUI which is able to generate GUI Elements dynamically on the fly. Then you define in your modules via you own [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) or XML your Module. The GUI is then generated based on your definitions which you can load dynamically. I used that once to automatically generate a GUI where a user can build his own dynamic reports and once for come generic installer tool which could create a new workspace with checkout of projects in one case and build & deploy & run a webapp in tomcat.

**Pros:**

- Easy to start with
- You know the code (because you have written it)

**Cons:**

- Is very specific
- time-consuming since it supports only the things you programmed into the framework
- you can easily develop bad code if you do not know exaclty what you do / the requirements change / ...

**2. Use some execution engine** (e.g. [Rhino](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhino_%28JavaScript_engine%29) or [Nashorn (Java 8)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_%28JavaScript_engine%29) )

You can develop your modules in JS and either generate the GUI from some modules (like described in 1.) - which I would do in case of a Swing GUI or even create the output from JS (which I would do in case of a WebApp since its just printing html)

**Pros:**

- You can do everything which is supported in the engine / the module language
- You are much more flexible than with 1.
- Much less time needed

**Cons:**

- Need to understand how the engine works
- Starting is not as easy as 1. since you have more external dependencies
- you are limited by the limits of the engine (in case of js e.g. the sandboxing like no writing to files, no swing integration / interaction by default,...)

**3. OSGi / Spring dm Server**

You can as well create your modules in java with own packaging and deploying on the fly into your application with OSGi.

If you want this for an WebApplication I would look into Spring dm Server: http://static.springsource.com/projects/dm-server/1.0.x/programmer-guide/html/ch03s02.html

Otherwise, OSGi should be the better fit.

Since there is much documentation out there on these two topics I wont go more into deep here.

**Pros:**

- You can do everything because your modules will be just java
- You use java well established standard mechanisms

**Cons:**

- Need to understand how the framework works
- Starting is not as easy as 1. or 2. since you will have to understand the techniques used
- more external dependencies

If my answer helped you, I would be happy if you accept it, if not please provide more detailled information on what you want to achieve and what are your requirements.

Regards, Manuel

Comment: You can find a good OSGi tutorial here: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/OSGi/article.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, even though it's already 4 years ago. OSGi might be the answer nowadays.